# Ember.js "Each" trouble

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember.js I have this model:

```
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string"),
    ean: DS.attr("number"),
    price: DS.attr("number"),
    units: DS.attr("number"),
    product_states: DS.hasMany('App.ProductState')
});

App.ProductState = DS.Model.extend({
    price: DS.attr("number"),
    units: DS.attr("number"),
    product_id: DS.belongsTo('App.Product'),
    user_id: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
    created: DS.attr("date")
});
```

And I have this each:

```
        {{#if view.product}}
            {{#each item in App.ProductState.find({ product_id: view.product.id})}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{view.product.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.price}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.units}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.created}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
```

Which gives me this error (Chrome):

```
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 6:
...in App.ProductState.find({ product_id: v
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'
```

I get this error when I am loading the page. In the time of loading the view.product is set to NULL. The each is inside of jQuery UI dialogue and its content is set dynamically as a result of button through `view.set("product",product);`.

Setting the product object works because when I want to just print out a product variable in the dialogue window it works just fine but it crashes when I am using the each.

In my opinion Ember ignores the if condition and tries to run through the each cycle which gives the error. Other option is that I am just using the find method wrong (btw. Ember guide tells you how to set model relationships but as far as I know does not mention what effect they have and how to use them properly).

Is it possible to work around the problem? Maybe something like running the each in javascript function instead of template or something?

Comment: Using the framework, you should load the data into a Controller, and then display it using the View.

Comment: I am sorry, but that's too general.

Comment: Sure, but also core to the framework that is Ember.js. Without more detail of your code, it is the best I can do. For instance:

Do you use routing? If so, do you set the model for the relevant route?
If not, how is your application view defined? What other elements are you showing, and how?

The essence is that a view is underpinned with a controller, and that controller's `content` has either one or multiple records (model instances), based on the type of find you use to fill it, or the way you instance it (so either an ObjectController or an ArrayController).

Answer (score 2):

You can not put javascript into handlebars templates (the views). If you need to to use straight up javascript code to do some special presentation processing then you should be using handlebars helpers which are covered here: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/

In your specific example since `product_states` is a property of `Product` you can just access the `product_states` property directly and ember / ember data will load the data when you request it and then update the when the data comes back from the server.

```
{{#if view.product}}
    {{#each item product.product_states)}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{view.product.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.price}}</td>
            <td>{{item.units}}</td>
            <td>{{item.created}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Note the convention in ember is to have properties camelCased. So your `Product` model should have a `productStates` property, and your `ProdcutState` model should have a `userId` property`. Not sure if this will mess up materialization of your json fromt he server or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the great insight but the solution still doesnt work and somehow I am still getting the same error: Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 6:
...tem in view.product.product_states)}}  
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

Comment: Maybe I should repeat that at the time of loading the page and firing this error the view.product is NULL because I dont know the right object until the user clicks a button.